# How to require fixture_builder in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, fixtures

I have a Rails 4.1 project that uses RSpec and Cucumber. 
I've recently added fixture_builder.

fixture_builder.rb includes logic to rebuild fixtures any time the file changes. 
This works fine for RSpec with `require 'fixture_builder'` in spec_helper.rb.

However, when running Cucumber tests fixture_builder.rb is not called, so fixtures are not updated if any changes have been made to fixture_builder.rb.

Is there an equivalent config file like spec_helper.rb for Cucumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Cucumber loads all *.rb files in the same directory as the feature(s) it's running and all subdirectories of that directory, so you can put your `require` in any file you want in any of those directories.

The conventional thing to do is to put 'support' code like `require` in `features/support/env.rb`, or in another file in `features/support` if your `env.rb` gets too big.

The cucumber-rails gem provides a generator that sets up Cucumber to work with Rails. If you haven't already, install the gem and run

```
rails g cucumber:install
```

to create `features/support/env.rb` and the rest of the usual Rails + Cucumber setup.